# Change sbt log tags: info,warn,success,error

Tags: scala, sbt

By default, sbt has the tags `[info]`,`[warn]`,`[success]`,`[error]` (with the colors white, yellow, green and red) for different log messages or throws to the command line. I feel that if they were shorter and the same length, they would be less distracting in my console.

I want to change them into `[i]`,`[w]`,`[s]`,`[e]` while keeping their colors. How can I change the log type identifiers? I am not using any logging packages.

Answer (score 0):

The tags are hard-coded into the default logger. To override them, you would have to create your own implementation of `sbt.Logger` and override the `logManager` setting with a `sbt.LogManager` that constructs such a logger.